# Stored fields in Solr are getting displayed in queries , why?

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I am new to using Solr , and I have made a new core and copied the default `schema.xml` to the `conf/` folder. The changes I have made is very trivial .

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

As you can see, I set the `id` field to **stored=false**. As per my understanding, the field `id` should not be displayed now when I do a query search. But that is not happening. I have tried restarting solr instance, and did the query to index the file again.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/TwitterCore/update/json?commit=true' 
  --data-binary @$(echo TwitterData_Core_Conf/TwitterText_en_demo.json) 
  -H 'Content-type:application
```

As per [Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToReindex) , this should have re-indexed my file. However when I run my query again, I still see the `Id` .

An example of the document returned (this is not the complete JSON node , I just copied some parts ) :

```
"text": [
      "RT @FollowTrainTV: Moonseternity just joined #FollowTrainTV - Watch them stream on http://t.co/oMcOGA51kT"
    ],
    "lang": [
      "en"
    ],
    "id": "0a8edfea-68f7-4b05-b370-27b5aba640b7", // I dont want to see this
    "_version_": 1512067627994841000
```

Maybe someone can give me detailed steps on re-indexing.

Comment: I am thinking, you cleared the old data before re-indexing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the schema.xml file and restart the solr-server, the changes only apply for new documents. This means you have to clear the index and re-index all documents (Except at query tokenizer, these changes are active immediately after server restart, but this is not the case here). After re-indexing, the `id` field should not be visible any more.

Another remark: You don't have to test your queries with curl. When you connect to `http://localhost:8983/solr` with your web-browser you should find an admin interface there. There you can select a core and test your queries.

Comment: I tried to do this   `curl http://<URL>:<port>/solr/update?strea
m.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*:*%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E` but I keep getting 404 error.   Exact error is `Problem accessing /solr/update` . I don't know what is wrong now.

Comment: The easiest thing would be to delete the `data/` folder from the index on the `solr-server`. After deleting this folder and restarting the server you can reindex your documents. Then you shouldn't see the ID any more.

Comment: @CyprUS You can use this command to clear the solr indexes: `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/update?commit=true -H 'Content-Type:text/xml' --data-binary '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'`

Comment: my mistake was not to add the core name. thanks @abhishekbafna

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/docvalues.html document.

> Non-stored docValues fields will be also returned along with other
>   stored fields when all fields are
>   specified to be returned (e.g. “fl=*”) for search queries depending on
>   the effective value of the useDocValuesAsStored parameter for each
>   field. For schema versions >= 1.6, the implicit default is
>   useDocValuesAsStored="true".

The String field type has docValues="true"  . That is the reason why it is appearing in the search response.

You can either add the useDocValuesAsStored="false" parameter to the field or you can use a different fieldType, say text_general.